# What is Cosecant inverse of $x$ equal to?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

What is $\csc^{-1}x$ = equal to?

Could anyone tell me the answer to this question?

This question was given to me exactly the same way I have written it here, they didn't ask for anything else but the value.

Comment: Is it possible that there was some context that would have told you something about $x$? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: No there was nothing ..

Comment: So you were walking down the street minding your own business when an apparition of the archangel Gabriel unexpectedly appeared before you and commanded you to answer that question? I can't help suspecting that's not exactly what happened. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: I received a text message with multiple questions and this is one of them.

Comment: Out of the blue?  You were not expecting a text message with questions about mathematics before and you never heard of mathematics before that, until a stranger sent you this unexpected query?  That's not so different from an archangel.  The alternative is that there's some context that you haven't told us about. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 1):

$$\csc^{-1}(x)=\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$$

Comment: Are there any other values as well or just this one? Because if its a inverse derivative then the value would be different.

Comment: Just like @Ian said!

Comment: Yeh, a little context would help provide a suitable answer.

Comment: So basically this is the simple value of the inverse trigonometric identity?

Answer (score 1):

To the power of negative one has two possible meanings (without context):

- reciprocal - i.e. $\csc^{-1}x = \sin x$
- inverse - i.e. $\csc^{-1}x = \operatorname{arccsc} x$

Assuming you have only recently starting doing $cosec$ I would say the first option is more likely what you were expected to give.

Comment: What would be your answer if it was asked to you because I don't know if I was asked the inverse trigonometric identity value or derivative of an inverse function or whatever else. What answer is most appropriate?

Comment: Is that the entire question? "What is it equal to?" Nothing else following or preceding the question? Given the limited scope of the question it's probably the first.

Comment: Well I am studying Calculus as well right now, not just the trigonometric and yes the question was cosec^x=? But the questions were combined from my course part 1 and 2, in part 1 we studied trignometry

Comment: Given your situation as a teacher I'd be expecting the first answer. The first demonstrates understanding of what $cosec$ means where as the second is simply a definition.

Comment: Okay thanks. I'll let you know the right answer after the results then

Comment: Proper notation is $\sin x$, not $sin x$.  I edited this answer accordingly. ${}\qquad{}$